# Unable to connect to vrde virtualbox VM remotely

Tags: virtual-machines, virtualbox, headless

So I've remotely created my first headless using ssh. Now I'm attempting to connect to this VM using RDP so I can install Ubuntu Server, but I cannot get connected at all.

When starting the VM everything appears fine:

```
$ vboxheadless -s WebTesting
Oracle VM VirtualBox Headless Interface 4.0.16
(C) 2008-2012 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

VRDE server is listening on port 4455.
```

And `showvminfo` shows:

`VRDE:            enabled (Address 0.0.0.0, Ports 4455, MultiConn: off, ReuseSingleConn: off, Authentication type: null)`

However I'm still prompted with the "enter your credentials" screen every time I attempt to connect. From reading the documentation null shouldn't prompt me with this screen at all...

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

P.S. I am using ssh tunneling in putty to tunnel in to my network.

Comment: Are you positive that the authentication error is coming from virtualbox, and not from something along your tunnel?

Comment: Not sure, I assume no I haven't set up anything else that would require authentication. I'll have to try it when I return home next week.